# How to accommodate null values in an SQL SELECT statement with a WHERE that includes an operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I can successfully avoid broken SQL statements if I am querying a row that includes a null column value with

```
IFNULL('column_name',''),
```

but when I try this with an SQL statement that contains a comparison operator, such as

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE IFNULL('pay','') <= $pay"
```

if pay is null, I get a "not a number error" like

```
ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'
```

As you can see from the SQL statement, there is a NaN contained within.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    ts.users_user_id 
  FROM
    subjects s 
    LEFT JOIN teachers_subjects ts 
      ON s.subject_ID = ts.subject_id 
    JOIN users_teachers ut 
      ON ut.user_id = ts.users_user_id 
    LEFT JOIN stations st 
      ON st.station_id = ut.station_id 
    LEFT JOIN majors mj 
      ON mj.major_id = ut.major_id 
  WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND IFNULL(ut.pay, 10) >= NaN 
    AND (ut.pay <= 500 
      OR ut.pay IS NULL)) qualified 
  JOIN users u 
    ON qualified.users_user_id = u.user_id 
  JOIN users_teachers ut 
    ON qualified.users_user_id = ut.user_id 
  JOIN teachers_subjects ts2 
    ON qualified.users_user_id = ts2.users_user_id 
  JOIN subjects s2 
    ON ts2.subject_id = s2.subject_id 
  LEFT JOIN stations st 
    ON ut.station_id = st.station_id
```

I can't replace `pay` with an arbitrary number value because I am using this in a pay filter. I need the SQL statement to just return rows that include a null value for pay, all other WHERE conditions being met, of course.

Answer (score 3):

the best way is not to replace NULL at all but have a separate condition checking NULL. you can then include/exclude this as needed.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE pay IS NULL
OR (other conditions)
```

Looking again closely, another issue with your code is that you are using a numeric comparison operator but replacing with a string '' is an empty string - the wrong type
I'm not sure why you have the NaN included within the query, or the WHERE 1 = 1 since that always evaluates to true...

```
WHERE ( ut.pay IS NULL OR ut.pay <= 500)
```

should work fine by itself.

Edit: reversed operators

Comment: so I am not actually typing in NaN, it just appears in my SQL statement if ut.pay is NULL. I have the WHERE 1 = 1 in there because if I am appending additional constraints they all start with " AND ". If I write WHERE 1 = 1 AND (ut.pay <= $pay OR ut.pay IS NULL), I get "NaN" for $pay

Comment: sorry, I should have reversed the statements, IS NULL should come first since usually the next statement in an OR won't evaluate if the first statement is true. a more robust answer would be AND (ut.pay IS NULL OR (ut.pay IS NOT NULL AND ut.pay <= 500 ))

Answer (score 0):

[`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is a special floating point value meaning "not a number". It is usually created by dividing zero by zero.

Your SQL diver is expecting `pay` to be numeric, so it isn't wrapping the value in quotes for the database, however when rendered to a string the `NaN` floating point value is literally `NaN`. Not being in quotes, the SQL parser assumes it to be a column name.

Check your application to ensure that `pay` is not being divided by zero before bring passed to your SQL driver.